# How to send Jenkins email notification with HTML file attachment with proper format using emailext

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-email-ext

I'm trying to send an email notification with sonar issues-report from Jenkins using emailext. If I attach only the issues-report.html, I get the report without proper format and images missing. Is there any way to attach the complete directory so that .css and .png are also available for the html file to displayed in proper format.

This is my File with absolute path: /var/jenkins_home/jobs/project-name/workspace/target/sonar/issues-report/issues-report.html

Also, for me the FILE syntax doesnt accept the absolute path or relative path. It works only when I give ${FILE,path="**/issue-report.html"}

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way currently to attach a html file with all dependencies